# How to resize my partition on virtualbox with Debian?

Tags: memory-management, debian, virtualbox, partition

I already created space in the virtualbox so you can see this free 55gb.
But when i want to delete partition 2 and partition 5, i get an error message: `rror deleting partition /dev/sda5: warning partition dev/sda5 is being used are you sure you want to continue` and i cant do nothing with it.

I tried to delete these partition with `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` and after that I deleted these partition, but nothing changed, they are stayed there. How can incrase my SDA1 dark size then?

[image]

I know, it isn't a programming question, but i tried many links and i haven't got any idea how can I increase my Partition1..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a gparted live cd that you'll find here https://gparted.org/livecd.php.

Then boot your VM on it (since it's a virtual machine you won't have to burn a real cd) and follow the steps (there are plenty of tutos with screen captures on the net, won't try to make one more here).

Comment: This link looks matching your needs https://www.jesusamieiro.com/increase-an-ext4-partition-with-gparted/